# Python pandas dataframe, how to get the set number

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here is eaxmple:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([('apple'),('apple'),('apple'),('orange'),('orange')],columns=['A'])

df
Out[5]: 
        A
0   apple
1   apple
2   apple
3  orange
4  orange
```

I want to assign a number next to it, example, apple is the first set of list ['apple','orange'], B column is 1, then 2 for orange:

```
        A   B
0   apple   1
1   apple   1
2   apple   1
3  orange   2
4  orange   2
```

Bellow wouldn't work.

```
df['B']=df['A'].tolist().index(df['A']) +1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) function. This function is used to convert arrays into categorical ones.

[`pd.Series.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html) is also available as a method of `pd.Series` objects:

```
codes, _ = df["A"].factorize()
df["B"] = codes + 1

print(df)
        A  B
0   apple  1
1   apple  1
2   apple  1
3  orange  2
4  orange  2
```

Answer (score 2):

use [`groupby ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-ngroup) + 1 with `sort=False` to ensure groups are enumerated in the order they appear in the DataFrame:

```
df['B'] = df.groupby('A', sort=False).ngroup() + 1
```

`df`:

```
        A  B
0   apple  1
1   apple  1
2   apple  1
3  orange  2
4  orange  2
```